# Image doesn't display

Tags: php

I have this code, I want to resize the picture, it manage to do the first one which 100x100 but not the others. I don't see why it doesn't work, it doesn't have any error. I'm a php newbie, doesn't really know what went wrong, but as you can see as the code does works for the 1st one but why doesn't work for the others?

```
    <?php

function thumbnail($image, $width, $height) {

    $image_properties = getimagesize($image);
    $image_width = $image_properties[0];
    $image_height = $image_properties[1];
    $image_ratio = $image_width / $image_height;
    $type = $image_properties["mime"];

    if(!$width && !$height) {
        $width = $image_width;
        $height = $image_height;
    }
    if(!$width) {
        $width = round($height * $image_ratio);
    }
    if(!$height) {
        $height = round($width / $image_ratio);
    }


    if($type == "image/jpeg") {
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        $thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    } elseif($type == "image/png") {
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        $thumb = imagecreatefrompng($image); 
    } elseif($type == "image/gif") {
        header('Content-type: image/gif');
        $thumb = imagecreatefromgif($image);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    $temp_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($temp_image, $thumb, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $image_width, $image_height);
    $thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbnail, $temp_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);

    if($type == "image/jpeg") {
        imagejpeg($thumbnail);
    } 
    elseif($type == "image/jpeg") {
        imagepng($thumbnail);
    } 
    elseif($type == "image/gif") {
        imagegif($thumbnail);
    }

    imagedestroy($temp_image);
    imagedestroy($thumbnail);


}

$pic_size = array();

// Adjust size

$pic_size['height'][0] = 100;
$pic_size['width'][0] = 100;

$pic_size['height'][1] = 200;
$pic_size['width'][1] = 200;

$pic_size['height'][2] = 300;
$pic_size['width'][2] = 300;

$pic_size['height'][3] = 400;
$pic_size['width'][3] = 400;

$pic_size['height'][4] = 500;
$pic_size['width'][4] = 500;

$total_pic_size= count($pic_size['height']);

    $x = 0;

   foreach(array_keys($pic_size['height']) as $x) {
        thumbnail($_GET["img"], $pic_size['width'][$x], $pic_size['height'][$x]);
        echo '<img src="index.php?w='.$pic_size['width'][$x].'&h='.$pic_size['height'][$x].'&img='.$_GET["img"].'" />';
        $x++;
    }



?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @PedroLobito I did but nothing reporting error. I even checked the php error logs, but there is no error at all.

Comment: You create image but never save it into server, function has no return value. `count($total_pic_size)` returns 2, but it doesn't matter now.

Comment: @panther How do I save it then? And I have updated the count recursive. So now it loops 5 now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate only two times, because

```
 $total_pic_size= count($pic_size);// is 2
```

Change that to:

```
$total_pic_size= count($pic_size['height']);
```

Or use foreach:

```
foreach(array_keys($pic_size['height']) as $x)
```

And don't use `COUNT_RECURSIVE` here, it will return wrong number again, counting in the `width` and `height` keys.

Also `thumbnail` function has `header` call in it, which cannot be called after `echo`, which in your case, is called after echo, in your loop. You should see the warning saying "Headers already sent".

You can save the image to file and echo image with file path as a source. Remove the `header` calls and let your `thumbnail` function save it and return the file name, for example:

```
imagejpeg($thumbnail, $filename);
return $filename;
```

and use the output as `src` of the echoed image.

Comment: Good catch there! I have updated with count recursive.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$total_pic_size` is always `2`.

```
$total_pic_size = count( $pic_size['width'] );
```

This will give you the correct number of items and the loop should run not only once.

You should also change the loop-condition:

```
while ($x <= $total_pic_size) {
```

**#Update 1**

You can try something like this:

```
// ...

$pic_sizes[0]['height'] = 100;
$pic_sizes[0]['width'] = 100;

$pic_sizes[1]['height'] = 200;
$pic_sizes[1]['width'] = 200;

$pic_sizes[2]['height'] = 300;
$pic_sizes[2]['width'] = 300;

$pic_sizes[3]['height'] = 400;
$pic_sizes[3]['width'] = 400;

$pic_sizes[4]['height'] = 500;
$pic_sizes[4]['width'] = 500;

$img = $_GET["img"];
foreach ($pic_sizes as $pic_size) {
    thumbnail($img, $pic_size['width'], $pic_size['height']);
    echo '<img src="index.php?w='.$pic_size['width'].'&h='.$pic_size['height'].'&img='.$img.'" />';
}
```

**#Update 2:**

You already accepted another answere, but maybe this is also helpful for you. i found some more errors and logic-problems in your code... the code below works (without saving the thumbs).

```
<?php

function thumbnail($image, $width, $height) {
    $image_properties = getimagesize($image);
    $image_width = $image_properties[0];
    $image_height = $image_properties[1];
    $image_ratio = $image_width / $image_height;
    $type = $image_properties["mime"];

    if(!$width && !$height) {
        $width = $image_width;
        $height = $image_height;
    }
    if(!$width) {
        $width = round($height * $image_ratio);
    }
    if(!$height) {
        $height = round($width / $image_ratio);
    }


    if($type == "image/jpeg") {
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        $thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    } elseif($type == "image/png") {
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        $thumb = imagecreatefrompng($image); 
    } elseif($type == "image/gif") {
        header('Content-type: image/gif');
        $thumb = imagecreatefromgif($image);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    $temp_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($temp_image, $thumb, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $image_width, $image_height);
    $thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbnail, $temp_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);

    if($type == "image/jpeg") {
        imagejpeg($thumbnail);
    } 
    elseif($type == "image/png") {
        imagepng($thumbnail);
    } 
    elseif($type == "image/gif") {
        imagegif($thumbnail);
    }

    imagedestroy($temp_image);
    imagedestroy($thumbnail);
}

$img = $_GET["img"];

$gen = @$_GET["gen"];
$w = @$_GET["w"];
$h = @$_GET["h"];
if ( !$gen ) {
    $pic_sizes = array();

    // Adjust size
    $pic_sizes[0]['height'] = 100;
    $pic_sizes[0]['width'] = 100;

    $pic_sizes[1]['height'] = 200;
    $pic_sizes[1]['width'] = 200;

    $pic_sizes[2]['height'] = 300;
    $pic_sizes[2]['width'] = 300;

    $pic_sizes[3]['height'] = 400;
    $pic_sizes[3]['width'] = 400;

    $pic_sizes[4]['height'] = 500;
    $pic_sizes[4]['width'] = 500;

    foreach ($pic_sizes as $pic_size) {
        echo '<img src="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?w='.$pic_size['width'].'&h='.$pic_size['height'].'&img='.$img.'&gen=1" />';
    }
} else {
    thumbnail($img, $w, $h);
}
```

Comment: Good catch there! I have updated with count recursive.

Comment: Your count is too high with COUNT_RECURSIVE ( 10 instead of 5 !! ).

Comment: Updated my code but still doesn't solve the issue yet.

Comment: @user1544809 updated - glad to see you'r on the way to solving the problem.